# Printing in a function vs sequence of print statements in main_

Tags: python

I writing a program for Hangman in Python 2.7. I'm trying to get the program to create the gallows and the hanged figure rather than me assembling them as a string and placing them in a list. My problem is the output from successive print statements gives me what I want but when I put the code in a function the result is skewed e.g.

```
print chr(47).rjust(4), # Right arm          
print chr(124), # backbone
print chr(92) + chr(124) # Left arm + tree
```

gives me this `/|\ |` --- inner slashed are concatenated

In a function:

```
def erect_gallows(bad_guess):
    if bad_guess == 1:
        print chr() - - -
        .....
        .....
```

this gives me this --  `/  |  \  |` with the slashes separated, out of alignment. Don't know why the print statements work outside but not inside the function. The function does not return anything, it just prints.

Comment: Please supply the actual code, reduced to the minimum needed to show the problem.  What you've posted so far doesn't do it.  I get the same output from both the main and function versions.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of your code and a straight solution.  In short, I suggest that you quit fooling around with separate output fields in the print statement: just build the string you want and print it.

```
def erect_gallows(bad_guess):
  if bad_guess == 1:
    print chr(47).rjust(4), # Right arm          
    print chr(124), # backbone
    print chr(92) + chr(124) # Left arm + tree 


print "---   Main code   ---"
print chr(47).rjust(4), # Right arm          
print chr(124), # backbone
print chr(92) + chr(124) # Left arm + tree 
print "---   Func code   ---"
erect_gallows(1)
print "---   1-line code   ---"
print chr(47).rjust(4) + chr(124) + chr(92) + " " + chr(124)
```

Output:

```
---   Main code   ---
   / | \|
---   Func code   ---
   / | \|
---   1-line code   ---
   /|\ |
```